# Is there any function like clock() in c in php?

Tags: php, c, profiling, execution-time

I want to measure the execution time for php script~

Answer (score 3):

Use [`microtime`](http://php.net/microtime). Make sure to look at example #2.

Comment: Although note that `clock` returns CPU time rather than wall-clock time, so `microtime` is not a direct equivalent. Depending on what the script is doing, either one might be the more useful measure.

Answer (score 1):

With microtime: [example](http://www.developerfusion.com/code/2058/determine-execution-time-in-php/)

Answer (score 0):

`mixed microtime ([ bool $get_as_float ] )`

> `microtime()` returns the current Unix timestamp with microseconds. This function is only available on operating systems that support the `gettimeofday()` system call.

Answer (score 0):

As long as PHP is running on a Unix system, you can get a fairly accurate measurement of the time taken using the `time(1)` command.  See the manpage for usage and output information.

If you want to time a specific section of the script, for whatever reason, I would personally just copy/paste it into its own file and run `time(1)` on that.

If you need to use the return value within a php script, you can use output generated by `time(1)` from PHP by returning it into a string using either `shell_exec()` or the backtick (`) operator.  See the PHP manual for more information on that.

As for a native PHP implementation of the `clock(3)` function, I don't believe such a thing exists and if it does I don't think it's part of the standard library.

The `microtime` function used by other answers does something different to `clock(3)`, as has been pointed out by Steve Jessop.

Answer (score -1):

```
function get_microtime() {
    list($usec, $sec) = explode(" ", microtime()); 
    return ((float)$usec + (float)$sec); 
}
```

Comment: `microtime(true)` does the same, without needing string/array functions